# How to Hold on the Shift Button to Click on Object simultaniously in UFT?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

In My Application I need to click on Web Element with holding the shift button then it works fine So I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, you could find the answer by searching on Google.

[This link](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-Practitioners/How-to-perform-shift-click-through-QTP/td-p/4696685) probably has what you need, but to summarize:

> Try using the SendKeys method (you may need to look up the proper
>   syntax etc.)
>
> SendKeys (micShiftdown)
>   Click where you need to click
>   Click the second
>   selection SendKeys (micShiftup)
>
> Something like that.

There is also another suggestion in [here](http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/153096-how-hold-down-shift-key-click-button.html):

```
Window("Windows Internet Explorer").Type micShiftDwn

set abc =Browser("creationtime:=1").Page("title:=.*").WebE lement("innertext:=abc1","innerhtml:=abc1")

abc.click

set abc2 =Browser("creationtime:=1").Page("title:=.*").WebE lement("innertext:=abc2","innerhtml:=abc2")

abc2.Click

Window("Windows Internet Explorer").Type micShiftUp
```